# cannot retrieve data from mysql using json and put them in a custom listview with fragments

Tags: android, json, listview, fragment

I'm using in my application swipable tabs. I'm able to retrieve the data I want from MySQL and PHP but I'm not able to put them in a custom listview in this fragment 
anyone can help me?

```
    package com.example.tabswithswipe;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


import com.example.tabswithswipe.R;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class Movies extends ListFragment {

    // Progress Dialog 
    private ProgressDialog pDialog; 
    // Creating JSON Parser object 
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser(); 
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> newslist; 
    // url daftar rumah sakit 
    private static String url_news_list = "http://myandroidserver.web44.net/get_all_generalnews.php";
    // JSON Node names 

    public static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success"; 
    public static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products"; 
    public static final String TAG_PID = "pid"; 
    public static final String TAG_TITLE= "title"; 
    public static final String TAG_IMAGE_PATH = "path"; 
    public static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description"; 
    public static final String TAG_CREATED_AT = "created_at"; 

    Button ButttonInputRumahSakit; 
    // daftar_rs JSONArray 
    JSONArray daftar_rs = null; 
    ListView list; 
    ListAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_movies, container, false);



     // Hashmap for ListView 
        newslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading daftar rumah sakit in Background Thread 
        new LoadDaftarRumahSakitActivity().execute(); 

        // Get ListView 
        //list = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list); 

                 list = getListView();


                // on seleting single product
                // launching Edit Product Screen
                //list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    //@Override
                    //public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        //  int position, long id) {
                        // getting values from selected ListItem
                        // String pid = newslist.get(position).get("pid").toString();
                        // String title=newslist.get(position).get("title").toString();
                       // String description=newslist.get(position).get("description").toString();
                         //String time=newslist.get(position).get("created_at").toString();
                         //String path=newslist.get(position).get("path").toString();


                        // Starting new intent
                        //Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(),
                        //      MainActivity.class);
                        // sending pid to next activity
                        //in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);
                        //in.putExtra(TAG_TITLE, title);
                        //in.putExtra(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);
                        //in.putExtra(TAG_CREATED_AT, time);
                        //in.putExtra(TAG_IMAGE_PATH, path);


                        // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                        //startActivityForResult(in, 100);
                //  }
                //});







        return rootView;
    }

    public void SetListViewAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> daftar) { 

        adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), daftar); 
        list.setAdapter(adapter);       


        } 

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
        // if result code 100 
        if (resultCode == 100) { 
            // if result code 100 is received // means user edited/deleted record // reload this screen again 
            Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent(); 
            getActivity().finish(); startActivity(intent); 

            } 
        } 







/** * Background Async Task to Load all record data by making HTTP Request * */ 

class LoadDaftarRumahSakitActivity extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    /** * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog * */
    @Override protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute(); 
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity()); 
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading News..."); 
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false); 
        pDialog.setCancelable(false); 
        pDialog.show();
        } 
    /** * getting All record data from url * */

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) { 

        // Building Parameters 
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 

        // getting JSON string from URL 
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_news_list, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse 
        Log.d("response ", json.toString()); 

        try { 
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG 
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS); 
            if (success == 1) { 
                // Ada record Data (SUCCESS = 1) 
                // Getting Array of daftar_rs 
                daftar_rs = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS); 
                // looping through All daftar_rs 
                for (int i = 0; i < daftar_rs.length(); i++) { 
                    JSONObject c = daftar_rs.getJSONObject(i); 
                    // Storing each json item in variable 
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID); 
                    String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                    //String image_path = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE_PATH); 
                    String description = c.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION); 
                    //String created_at = c.getString(TAG_CREATED_AT); 

                    // creating new HashMap 
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value 
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id); 
                    map.put(TAG_TITLE, title); 
                    //map.put(TAG_IMAGE_PATH, image_path); 
                    map.put(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description); 
                    //map.put(TAG_CREATED_AT, created_at); 
                    // adding HashList to ArrayList 
                    newslist.add(map); 

                    } 
                } 
            else { 
                //Record Data (SUCCESS = 0)  
                getActivity().finish(); 
                } 
            } 
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
            } 
        return null; 
        } 

    /** * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog * **/ 

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) { 
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all record rumah sakit 
        pDialog.dismiss(); 
        // updating UI from Background Thread 
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
            @Override
            public void run() { 
                // updating listview 
                SetListViewAdapter(newslist); 
                } 
            }); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

and the logcat shows:

```
        01-01 12:32:50.099: I/dalvikvm(790): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
01-01 12:32:50.219: I/dalvikvm(790): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-01 12:32:50.600: I/dalvikvm(790): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
01-01 12:32:50.639: I/dalvikvm(790): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-01 12:32:50.729: D/AndroidRuntime(790): Shutting down VM
01-01 12:32:50.729: W/dalvikvm(790): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:328)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.getListView(ListFragment.java:222)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at com.example.tabswithswipe.Movies.onCreateView(Movies.java:73)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2092)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1064)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-01 12:32:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-01 12:32:51.109: I/dalvikvm(790): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
01-01 12:32:51.159: I/dalvikvm(790): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-01 12:32:51.430: I/dalvikvm(790): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
01-01 12:32:51.479: I/dalvikvm(790): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-01 12:32:52.710: D/dalvikvm(790): GC_CONCURRENT freed 226K, 4% free 9283K/9607K, paused 10ms+4ms
01-01 12:32:53.390: D/response(790): {"success":1,"products":[{"path":"https:\/\/www.google.com\/images\/srpr\/logo11w.png","created_at":"2013-12-13 09:06:56","title":"bekh","pid":"1","description":"bekhen"}]}
01-01 12:32:56.822: I/Process(790): Sending signal. PID: 790 SIG: 9
```

Comment: these are the data getting from the PHP: 
01-01 11:47:19.850: D/response(587): {"success":1,"products":[{"path":"https:\/\/www.google.com\/images\/srpr\/logo11w.png","created_at":"2013-12-13 09:06:56","title":"bekh","pid":"1","description":"bekhen"}]}

Comment: The logcat says you're calling `getListView()` in `Movies.onCreateView()` but there's no code to demonstrate that.

Comment: so what should i do ?

Comment: Update the question with your actual code that causes the exception.

Comment: this is the whole class and the logcat .

Comment: I resolved the problem :D i forgot about onresume() so ive put it and everything is good now :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is because you are calling  ***new LoadDaftarRumahSakitActivity().execute();***  before

```
list = getListView();
```

that's why it shows that ***Content view not yet created***

So change it:

```
list = getListView();
new LoadDaftarRumahSakitActivity().execute();
```

Comment: i tried it but it ddt worked anw i found the solution by putting onresume() and everything is good now, thank u for ur help :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's do a simple test. Could you print out in a log the json input you get in android? It will help us to know if what you receive in your app is what you expect. Then we can carry on with more tests.

Comment: my logcat shows what im getting from the link but i cant put them in the list .

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

You set ListView's adpater before initializing it. move `list = getListView();` before `new LoadDaftarRumahSakitActivity().execute();` as below:

```
list = getListView();
new LoadDaftarRumahSakitActivity().execute();
```

---

To process JSONArray, try this:

```
String jsonStr = db.getSomeJsonString();
try {
    ArrayList<String> dataArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String title = jsonObject.getString("Title");
        dataArray.add(title);
    }
//...
```

Comment: hey Ali thank u for your reply but where should i put this code to try it ?

Comment: and another question: what should i define db ?

Comment: Edit your Q and add exact LogCat output.